# Get method is converted to OPTIONS when hitting fetch api in React js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to hit below api and requires basic auth username and password and method allowed in this is only get

```
dispatch(requestBegin());
let apiPath = `xxxx/TEST/appservice/api/app/10/10000127201901`;
return fetch(apiPath, {
  method: 'get',
  headers : {
     "contentType":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization" : 'Basic '+btoa('xxx:xxx'),
    },
})
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch(getEventsEnds(json));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    dispatch(getEventsEnds());
  });
```

The error loged in console :

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.
>
> OPTIONS http://xxx/appservice/api/app/10/10000127201901 405 (Method
>   Not Allowed)

Can anyone please eplain when i m trying to hit get api then why is it showing options

Comment: You're serving your app on one port `2200` and your API is most likely on another port.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson so what can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That means your API server does not accept CORS request or requests originating from localhost.

Check out your API documentation but my guess is you won't be able to interact directly with it from your web app.

Your best bet is to use a proxy, you can develop one yourself or use something like node-http-proxy to proxy your API calls. (There are php or python equivalents)

The proxy server will be able to issue the requests and will then forward them to your app.

Suggested further reading: type understanding CORS on google and read more about it.

For local development, check out:

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Comment: any solutions from react end ? can we consume this kind of api? if no then whats the solution on api end do we have any examples on it please?

Comment: Please take the time to read about CORS, it is basic knowledge if you want to do front end development. Nothing you can do from front end side (React or not). If you need to use the API during development, use a proxy on your local machine (links added). When the time comes to deploy to production, make sure your domain is whitelisted by your API

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the client  api URL and server URL don't match, including the port number. In this case you need to enable your service for CORS which is cross origin resource sharing.

use npm install cors

refer this`[refer][1]`